# Why my function is being executed when I am just passing it's reference to the addEventListener?

Tags: reactjs

I have built a custom hook to easy show/hide element, I have a function which will hide element if I click outside the element, this is my hook code:

```js
const useToggle = () => {
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = React.useState(false);
  const ref = React.useRef();
  let isMounted = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
    console.log("Called");
    if (
      !ref.current ||
      (!ref.current.contains(e.target) && isMounted.current)
    ) {
      setIsToggled(false);
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    }
  };

  return {
    isToggled,
    setIsToggled,
    ref,
    handleOutsideClick,
  };
};

// import "./App.css";
function App() {
  const { handleOutsideClick, ref, isToggled, setIsToggled } = useToggle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsToggled(true);
          window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
        }}
      >
        Show Modal
      </button>
      {isToggled && (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "400px",
            height: "400px",
            backgroundColor: "seagreen",
          }}
          ref={ref}
        ></div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I click the show modal button the modal isn't being displayed because the handleOutsideClick function is being executed and it sets the state to false, I don't understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `click` event created when you use your button here:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    setIsToggled(true);
    window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  }}
>
```

Is going to [bubble up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture) and trigger the `click` listener you just registered on the window.

A simple solution would be to stop propagation when that initial click event is created:

```
<button
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsToggled(true);
    window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  }}
>
```

Comment: interesting, I had the same code on nextjs project it was working but not on a CRA app, I wonder if nextjs by default uses stopPropagation